# Cross-referencing double-digit figure numbers in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an issue with MS Word (2016), where the references to figures are not updating correctly anymore. My figure references, inserted as 'cross-reference' include the chapter number and sequence number based on the number of figures in the chapter (i.e. Figure 4.4 in Chapter 4).

The issue is that the second number does not update anymore, and is removed for all cross-references in my document (about ~200 of them), even though the link to the correct figure still works (it goes to the right figure when I click the cross reference).

[image: Broken figure cross-referencing]

I've tried using [this http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CombineXrefs.htm](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CombineXrefs.htm) website to enable "double-digit figure numbers", through changing the field codes, but to no avail:

> { REF _Ref218925266 # 0x.0x \h } turns into 0.40 for some reason

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Missing backslash before hash?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to do it. I've ended up changing everything manually in the end, but i'll leave the question open.